# Huge txt file with one column (text to columns in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggeling with one task that can save plenty of time. I'm new to Python so please don't kill me :)

I've got huge txt file with millions of records. I used to split them in MS Access, delimiter "|", filtered data so I can have about 400K records and then copied to Excel.

So basically file looks like:

[image]

What I would like to have:

[image]

I'm using Spyder so it would be great to see data in variable explorer so I can easily check and (after additional filters) export it to excel.

Comment: Would "storing the data in an SQL database" be an option for your use case?

Comment: It is stored in SQL database. Unfortunately its hard to improve sql query so I can receive much less records.

Comment: *"Unfortunately its hard to improve sql query "* - How so?

Comment: Specific formulas should be analyzed separately. I mean probably its improvable, but for me Python solution looks simpler. Just need to know how to fix text to columns and other filters should be simple as I used them before.

Comment: If it's simple to filter them from your CSV file, it's simple to filter them with SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the difference between the file and your output. Could you explain it?

Comment: As I dont have direct access to sql database (+ beginner sql knowledge) I would stay with Python solution for now. Could you please advise how to solve my problem?

Comment: The input is in 1 column. The output is first line split by "|" in 5 columns. Just same as text to columns from excel.

Comment: Have you tried using `pandas`? Reading your csv would be as easy as `df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', sep='|')`

Comment: Oh god. It works. I'm familiar with panda, just didn't know that I can use 'sep'. Many, many thanks!

Comment: If it is already stored in an SQL database, you probably don't need to transform it to text and and then parse it again with pandas *at all*. I still do not see why you're not using the SQL database as it is.

Comment: I would need to think about updating my sql queries then. Right now I need to store raw data so I ask for txt files, which are pretty light in comparison to xlsb.

Comment: I agree with @Tomalak though. If you are running a query to get it in text form, you could just as easily query it with python. I just suggested pandas because that was the question you asked.

Comment: I would say that thinking about updating your SQL queries is a more fruitful endeavor than devising all kinds of bent-over-backwards ways to *avoid* thinking about updating those SQL queries. :)

Comment: Ok I will definitely think about it then. Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I use LibreOffice so I'm not 100% sure about Excel but if you change the .txt to .csv and try to open the file with Excel, it should allow to change the delimiter from a comma to '|' and then import it directly. That work with LibreOffice Calc anyway.

[image]

Comment: Ye, in Excel its pretty simple. But this time I have millions of records so Python is my friend:)

Answer (score 0):

u have to split the file in lines then split the lines by the char l and map the data to a list o dicts.

```
with open ('filename') as file:
    data = [{'id': line[0], 'fname':line[1]} for line in f.readlines()]
```

you have to fill in tve rest of the fields

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with **pandas** will be much easier

Note: I am assuming that each entry is on a new line.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", delimiter='|')

# Do something here or let it be if you want to just convert text file to excel file

data.to_excel("data.xlsx")
```